# Azure virtual machine with older version of windows 10

Tags: azure, uwp, windows-10, azure-virtual-machine

I know how to make and use a VM on **Microsoft Azure** with **VS 2017** and latest version of windows 10 already installed and use it to develop or test **uwp** apps. but the problem is, my own laptop is usually on insider build and I am making uwp apps which have min support for creators update, so in order to make sure my app run fine on creators update, I need a machine which has **Windows 10 creators update installed on it.**

But azure always provides machines with latest versions installed only, right now it is fall creators update, soon it will be spring creators update. how can I make a VM on azure with visual studio 2017 installed, but I can choose to select an older version of windows 10 for testing purposes of my app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But azure always provides machines with latest versions installed only

It is similar to local machine that develop and test uwp apps. If you install the VS2017 with default options, it will only support SDK that matches the current operating system version. You could open **Visual Studio Installer** click **Modify** button select **individual components** and check older SDK you want use like follow screenshot.

[image]

You could modify your app's target version for testing after installed the old SDK.

[image]

**Update**

Conditional XAML is available starting with the Creators Update (version 1703, build 15063). To use conditional XAML, the Minimum Version of your Visual Studio project must be set to build 15063 (Creators Update) or later, and the Target Version be set to a later version than the Minimum.

If you want to install older version of windows 10 in the azure virtual machine, Please refer [Use Windows client in Azure for dev/test scenarios](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/client-images#eligible-offers).

Comment: I think you did not understand my question, I am creating an app with creators update as minimum version and fall creators update as target version. and my machine is on insiders build ( so I don't know whether it will run perfect on older 2 OS versions ) obviously I have all the sdks installed that is why my app supports those sdks. my question was regarding the testing machine. an app can have multiple sdks support, but a laptop cannot have multiple versions of windows 10 to test the app on all versions :) so I need a VM for that, I hope it is clear now?

Comment: btw I tried to set my project to target version "Creators Update" and now my app cannot build bcz its giving me errors, I do have lot of Conditional xaml code in my app, but still app is giving me error:  "The name "NavigationView" does not exist in the namespace "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"

Comment: The `NavigationView` only works in Windows 10 Fall Creators Update (introduced v10.0.16299.0), You need to modify the mini version to Windows 10 Fall Creators Update.

Comment: Zhu , No sir I don't have to do that because I am using conditional xaml and hence navigation view will only be active on fall creators update and that xaml will not even execute on creators update.

Comment: Yep, you could use conditional xaml to approach.

Comment: exactly, so adaptive code is not a problem for me, I am just looking for a way to test the app for all OS version it supports :)

Comment: I wonder  you could not run lower target version UWP in the operation system?

Comment: as I mentioned before, I tried to lower the target version of my app from project properties, but because I have a lot of conditional xaml for fall creators update, Visual studio gives me build errors if I try to do that.

Comment: I have offerID of 0063P and I can find windows 10 1709 in azure marketplace, but couldn't find 1703 ( which I need the most )

Comment: Have you checked [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/prepare-for-upload-vhd-image).

Comment: yeah its a long process to prepare and image and stuf which ive never tried before but ill try it